# Do we need a "layout-builder" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There just came on question in tagged in the title as there currently no [layout-builder](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout-builder) tag exists.

[Layout Builder - How do we programmatically place a section and then a block in that region on module install?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283638/layout-builder-how-do-we-programmatically-place-a-section-and-then-a-block-in)

Seems there are some few question which could benefit from it:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22layout+builder%22+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I think we do. Here it is:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/layout-builder

I don't have time to re-tag things at the moment, but go nuts if/when you do :)